# Using OpenShift template to conditionally include/exclude certain resources during apply

Tags: openshift

I am using Ansible to automate the `oc process -f allresources.yaml | oc apply -f -` command. Inside of `allresources.yaml` template, I have my routes, services, etc... I want to add an additional but optional route to the template. The template will deploy both HTTPS and (optionally) HTTP routes during the `oc apply` phase. Not always will the developers require an HTTP route, so I want this to be configurable in the repository Jenkinsfile.

The question comes down to this: Is there a way to add a selector/conditional to `oc process` that will only evaluate resources that match the selector/conditional. Ultimately, Ansible will evaluate Jenkins configuration and determine how to process the `oc process` command.

Something along these lines:

```bash
oc process -f allresources.yaml APP=someapp ENV=dev --ignore="HTTPRoute" | oc apply -f -"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for conditionals in openshift templates. However, since you're using Ansible, you have lots of options:

- You can have multiple templates and apply them conditionally.

  ```
  - name: apply main templates
    shell: oc process -f allresources.yaml | oc apply -f-

  - name: apply route templates
    when: route_required
    shell: oc process -f route.yaml | oc apply -f-
  ```
- You could use Jinja templates via the Ansible `template` module instead of openshift templates.

  ```
  - name: render templates
    template:
      src: allresources.yaml.j2
      dest: allresources.yaml

  - name: apply generated manifests
    command: oc apply -f allresources.yaml
  ```
- If you don't like jinja2 templates, you could do something similar using an external templating tool like [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/learning/), for example:

  ```
  - name: apply generated manifests
    shell: jsonnet --tla-code route_required={{ route_required }} allresources.json | oc apply -f-
  ```